# Python : No such a file directory

Tags: python

I m new to python and i was trying to send attached email through Gmail and the path of attachment i'm giving unable to locate Python.

```
class Email(object):
    def __init__(self, from_, to, subject, message, message_type='plain',
                 attachments=None, cc=None, message_encoding='us-ascii'):
        self.email = MIMEMultipart()
        self.email['From'] = from_
        self.email['To'] = to
        self.email['Subject'] = subject
        if cc is not None:
            self.email['Cc'] = cc
        text = MIMEText(message, message_type, message_encoding)
        self.email.attach(text)
        if attachments is not None:
                mimetype, encoding = guess_type(attachments)
                if mimetype ==None:
                    mimetype = "text/html"
                mimetype = mimetype.split('/', 1)
                with open(os.path.join(attachments, 'TestReport.html')) as f:
                 attachment = MIMEBase(mimetype[0], mimetype[1])
                 attachment.set_payload(f.read())
                 f.close()
                encode_base64(attachment)
                attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
                                      filename=os.path.basename(attachment))
                self.email.attach(attachment)
```

Below code is the file I'm executing and throwing an error with  open(os.path.join(attachments, 'TestReport.html')) as f:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/RelianceJio/wallet-fp-automation/email_utils\TestReport.html'

```
from email_utils.Email import EmailConnection, Email

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(getcwd() + "/configuration.ini")

print 'I need some information...'
name = 'Lokesh Reddy'
email = 'lokeshreddyqa@gmail.com'
password = '***'
mail_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
to_email = 'lokeshreddz@gmail.com'
to_name = 'Lokesh Reddy'
subject = 'Sending mail easily with Python'
message = 'here is the message body'

#os.chdir(getcwd() + "\ TestReport.html")

MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

attachments =MYDIR

print 'Connecting to server...'
server = EmailConnection(mail_server, email, password)
print 'Preparing the email...'
email = Email(from_='"%s" <%s>' % (name, email),  # you can pass only email
              to='"%s" <%s>' % (to_name, to_email),  # you can pass only email
              subject=subject, message=message, attachments=attachments)
print 'Sending...'
server.send(email)
print 'Disconnecting...'
server.close()
print 'Done!'
```

Comment: `No such file or directory: 'C:/RelianceJio/wallet-fp-automation/email_utils\TestReport.html'` gives you the answer, your file does not exists at this path

Comment: How are `pyunit` and `python-unittest` related to this?

Comment: the file exists at the same path

Comment: You should check if the problem is with the path separator. You are mixing `/` and `\\`,

Comment: Mixing / and \ can, but should not be a problem in this case, as `\T` is not a valid escape sequence. Another problem might be that paths in Python are case sensitive, whereas in Windows they aren't. The directory came from Python itself, so that should be fine. My guess would be that the filename is actually 'testreport.html' or maybe `TestReport.HTML'.

Comment: my code worked with this line of code --  attachments = [x for x in os.listdir(".") if x.endswith(".html")]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to attach TestReport.html present in the floder 'C:/RelianceJio/wallet-fp-automation/email_utils\'. Please check whether the file is present in the folder specified. If not make sure that the file is present in that folder or else pass the correct attachment folder.

Comment: my code worked with this line of code -- attachments = [x for x in os.listdir(".") if x.endswith(".html")] –

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   C:\\RelianceJio\\wallet-fp-automation\\email_utils\\TestReport.html
```

You gave "\" instead of "\".

Your directory:

```
C:/RelianceJio/wallet-fp-automation/email_utils**\**TestReport.‌​html
```

Comment: IMHO, // does not make much sense, particularly on Windows. Did you mean \\ instead? Note that the path was not specified by OP but given by a Python function `os.path.dirname`!

Comment: my code worked with this line of code -- attachments = [x for x in os.listdir(".") if x.endswith(".html")] –

Comment: glad to hear that :)